# Angular UI grid column merge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gridview, angular-ui-grid

I have a angular grid that I am using to display data. Now what I want is that two columns to be merged.

[image: Grid image]

Now as seen,the parameter column is merged two into one,as for population statistics and sample statistics. How can I achieve this?
Currently the code I'm using is shown below:

```
gridOptions.columnDefs = [

      {field : 'parameters',width:150,displayName : 'SETTINGS.STATISTICS.PARAMETERS', headerCellFilter:'translate'},
      {field : 'popAngle',width:200,displayName : 'SETTINGS.STATISTICS.POPULATION_ANGLE', headerCellFilter:'translate'},
      {field : 'popTorque',width:150,displayName : 'SETTINGS.STATISTICS.POPULATION_TORQUE', headerCellFilter:'translate' },
      {field : 'statsAngle',width:200,displayName : 'SETTINGS.STATISTICS.SAMPLE_ANGLE', headerCellFilter:'translate'},
      {field : 'statsTorque',width:100,displayName : 'SETTINGS.STATISTICS.SAMPLE_TORQUE', headerCellFilter:'translate' }

];
```

But this is not merging any columns,just plain and simple. How do I merge?

Comment: Could you please add reference from where you got this..

Comment: @ShivekParmar This code we are using in our project.And as mentioned above,that is our requirement to merge the header as shown in the image